# Is there a better way to listen for a condition variable in a background thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I need to wait for a GPS signal to be acquired by my location handler class before assigning the latitude and longitude to an api query class. In this inner class I'm using a background process to wait until the variable is changed from null before passing it into the API class. I'm sure there might be a more efficient way to do this, but I don't see what it is.

```
private class listenForLocation extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, locationHandler> {

protected locationHandler doInBackground(Activity... params) {
        locationHandler curLoc = new locationHandler(params[0]);
        curLoc.askForlocation();
        while (curLoc.getCurrentLong() == null){
            // wait for an actual location update
        }
        return curLoc;
    }//doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(locationHandler result) {
        yelpDataExecutor load = new yelpDataExecutor();
        load.execute(result.getCurrentLat(),result.getCurrentLong());

    }//On Post Execute

}//listen for location Class
```

Comment: Get rid of this class. Call `curLoc.askForLocation()`. Have `locationHandler` raise an event using an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.). Have your activity listen for that event, then perform the code that you currently have in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I'll check those out.